# Django rotated log files data is lost

Tags: django, logging, uwsgi

I launch my Django 1.8 app with UWSGI in 10 processes. UWSGI is set up under the virtualenv.

Django file logging config is the following:

```
LOG_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/app_logs/debug.log'
...
    'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
    'file': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': LOG_FILE_PATH,
        'formatter': 'verbose',
        'when': 'midnight',
        'interval': 1,
        'backupCount': 0,
...
```

When I start UWSGI logging works just fine - I see debug.log being updated with entries. As well as I see the activity in UWSGI log file:

```
/var/log/uwsgi/mysite.log
```

After the midnight, I see the Django log files rotation happened (debug.log.2015-09-30 is indeed created), but it is almost empty:

```
$ cat debug.log.2015-09-30
INFO 2015-10-01 17:45:21,362 MainScreen 1836 140697212401600 MainScreen is called with the following parameters: {}
ERROR 2015-10-01 17:45:21,362 MainScreen 1836 140697212401600 Login error: NotEnoughParametersError {}
```

Also, the current log file debug.log is not being updated anymore with the app activity. **And so does UWSGI log file**:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/uwsgi/mysite.log
```

remains silent while the app is up and running. If I restart UWSGI everything gets back to normal until the next midnight.

I suspect this might be a concurrency issue with Django logging. How do I overcome that? And how do I fix UWSGI logs too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Django log I resolved the issue by substituting TimedRotatingFileHandler with [ConcurrentLogHandler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ConcurrentLogHandler/).